# How to work with SASS in different project?

Tags: sass

While I was learning SASS, I have learned how to install SASS and dev-dependencies using npm package.
Now I want to work on my own project, so how should I work with SASS ?
Do I have to install SASS again ?
If not then how to use existing sass in my project and also the other dependencies like concatenation, auto pre-fixer. Especially when they are updated.

Comment: Do you want to use sass in some framework?

Comment: No. It's a regular project using only HTML & CSS. I want to use pre-processor SASS instead of CSS. But I have already installed SASS for previous project which was first SASS project. But I'm stuck, I don't know how to use it in next project